# How to get a drop-down working in C# ASP.NET razor mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm sure tons of people have had similar issues but I've read over every thread I could find and it still won't work. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Idea behind the below webpage:

So the drop-down auto fills from values from a database (which it does), then when the user selects a particular value the page responds e.g. with a messagebox etc.

Model :

```
public class Countries
{
    public int CountriesId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{

    // This property will be populated with the selected Countries's ID when user posts the form
    public int SelectedCountriesId { get; set; }

    // After form submission, this property will hold the selected Countries's name
    public string CountriesName { get; set; }

    // Option Label for DropDownList
    public string OptionLabel { get; set; }

    public class ItemListModelViewModel
    {

        // All the Countriess which will be in the list
        public IEnumerable<Countries> CountriesList { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SelectListViewModel: name indicates that select list items are collected as list of SelectListItem type
    /// </summary>
    public class SelectListViewModel 
    {

        // This will hold a constructed selectlist with Countries items
        public SelectList CountriesList { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelectListItemViewModel 
    {

        // All the Countriess which will be in the list
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CurrentInventoryModel m)
{


    var Countries = Help.GetCountries();



    m.CountriesList = Countries;



    m.CountriesName = Countries.Where(c => c.CountriesID == m.SelectedCountriesID).FirstOrDefault().Name;

    return View(m);
}
```

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="display-field" align="left">
            <select name="mydropdown">
                @foreach (var lLMMI in lIM)
                {
                    <option value="@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode">@locItem.Key.Loc.N (@lLMMI.Key.Loc.Code)</option>}
            </select>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
}
```

I want to fix the drop box, as I can't get it to pass the selected drop down value through to a message box for instance. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question -Please fix the drop box, as I can't get it to pass the selected drop down value through to a message box for instance

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the selected drop down value through to a message box"?

Comment: The dropdown above, I want it so when the user clicks on an item. it passes the value through to the action-result, so a message-box can be formed etc.

Comment: so you want to pass the selected item back to the controller?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. All the posted code from your models/controller has no relevance to anything going on in your view, and it's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve even then. Please take some time to thoroughly work out your question, posting relevant and only relevant code.

Comment: Yes, so an action actually occurs when an item is selected in the drop down

Comment: It's really difficult to help with the unrelated code snippets you have posted, but if you want the select list selected value to bind to a property on your model then the id of the select list has to match the property name.

Comment: You can make jQuery Ajax call and on success you can do stuff there.. thats it.

Answer (score 3):

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a country")]
[Display(Name = "Country")]
public int SelectedCountriesId { get; set; }
public string CountryName { get; set; }
public SelectList CountriesList { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
var listOfCountries = Help.GetCountries();
m.CountriesList = new SelectList(listOfCountries, "id", "coutry_name");
```

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountriesId, 
                        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)model.CountriesList, 
                        "-- Select a country --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCountriesId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add an `onChange` event to your select:

```
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="onChange()">
```

Add a javascript function to handle it where you get the selected value and pass it as a parameter to your Action:

```
function onChange() {
    var item = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
    $.post('@Url.Content("ActionName")',
        { "item": item });
}
```

If you want to display a system message box with the selected value:

```
function onChange() {
    var item = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
    alert(item);
}
```